# Add Triples to Protege for querying

Tags: semantic-web, protege

I have the ontology and a file about 7.4 GB containing triples. How do I add this file of triples so that I can run queries on it ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to import you data into a triplestore.
See http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/SPARQL#The_sample_Data for an example how to import Data into a triple store - in this case blazegraph.

Different triplestores have different options. Protége is not so god for managing data directly. It's good for designing ontologies - that is specifying the schema/structure/model for the data. If you have the data in triples you might want to find out this structure by not only looking at the data but also finding sources for the underlying design. Of course you can sort of "reverse engineer" this by loading the triples into a triple store and trying queries.